# cache images that has been resized with php

Tags: php, cache, image

URL of the image is like this

```
resize.php?image=imagename.jpg&w=100&h=100
```

and I want to cache the result in RAM. Can APC of php do it? how? Or I must install something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use APC to store the result in RAM. You just need to install APC module, and then add code to store /fetch resized versions inside APC using `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()` functions.